# Instanciate concrete class a generic method in scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have a generic method which a generic type parameter `T` which is a subclass of `MyClass`. Inside that method, I want to create e new instance of `T`, how can I do that?

This doesn't work (because of type erasure):

```
object Demo extends App {
  def myMethod[T <: MyClass](): Unit = {
      val t = new T // gives error: class type required by T found 
  }
  myMethod[MySubclassA]()
}


abstract class MyClass
class MySubclassA extends MyClass
class MySubclassB extends MyClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails to work, but not (primarily) because of type erasure, but because your definition should make sense for all `T` which satisfy the type bounds, and `new T` doesn't. E.g. `T` can be `MyClass` or an abstract subclass, or a subclass without a parameter-less constructor, or a trait (traits can extend classes), or...

If a runtime error is good enough, you can go with Sergey Lagutin's solution. But more reasonable for most cases would be to pass some way to create a `T` to `myMethod`. Possibly as an implicit argument, e.g.

```
class Factory[T](f: () => T) {
  def make(): T = f()
}
object Factory {
  implicit val MySubclassAFactory = 
    new Factory(() => new MySubclassA) 
  implicit val MySubclassBFactory = 
    new Factory(() => new MySubclassB)
}
def myMethod[T <: MyClass](implicit factory: Factory[T]): Unit = {
  val t = factory.make()
  ...
}

myMethod[MySubclassA] // works
myMethod[MyClass] // compilation error
myMethod[ASubclassForWhichFactoryIsNotDefined] // compilation error
```

Comment: By passing implicit argument you mean : `def myMethod[T <: MyClass]()(implicit t: T)`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ClassTag` to achieve your goal:

```
def myMethod[T <: MyClass : ClassTag]: T =
  implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]

println(myMethod[MySubclassA]) // MySubclassA@66d2e7d9
println(myMethod[MySubclassB]) // MySubclassB@1efbd816
```